# "Google is not defined" error - Trying to create infowindow Google Maps

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps API, I want to create an infowindow everytime I place a marker (markers all stored in an array).
When declaring the infowindow:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

I get the error 'google is not defined'.

This only stops if I move this line of code inside the function that creates markers, but then I would be creating the variable infowindow everytime I placed a marker which I understand is bad practice?

I would prefer to declare infowindow at the start of my JS, and then just use it everytime a marker is placed.
I couldn't find anything that helped from the other answers on SO, I've tried reordering the JS files but nothing as worked so far.

Any tips would be welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because google maps is loaded asynchronously and you are calling this line before the google maps API has loaded.

This is how to wait until it's loaded:

```
<!-- include this snippet anywhere -->
<script>
  var infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
     infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  }
</script>

<!-- include this script in your footer...or anywhere really -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

For instance, if you tried to do something like this:

```
<script>
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Then you'd get an error, because `google` would not be defined when `var infoWindow = ...` is executed because the API has not loaded yet.

**You can only use any `google.maps.XXX` classes after your callback (e.g. initMap) has been executed**

Comment: this is great can't believe I didnt think of it, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a lot of time 'google is not defined'. I think Google Script has problems with FF-addon. FF has restart option, please try Help > restart with the Add-ons Disabled. :)

Comment: I've heard that also, however this isn't working for me in any browser!